# Enabling webgl in qtbrowser

Tags: webgl, qtwebkit, qt4.8

Myself a beginner in Qt. I need to enable webgl in my qtbrowser. So what all changes i need to make in the code of webkit in qt4.8.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us your effort marry... only then we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::WebGLEnabled, true);
```

[More info here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html)